# How to make 4 columns in bootstrap grid break to two then one column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my bootstrap code so far:

```
<div class="container-flex">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

A simple 4 column setup. Currently it breaks into single column on large (lg class) breakpoint. Is there any way I can set it up so it breaks into two columns on large breakpoint then into one column on medium (md class ) breakpoint? I've been looking over bootstrap tutorials and can't find any solution.

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noe562h0/

Comment: Do you want to break ```row``` in two column for ```lg```?? one column for ```md```?

Comment: Essentially on screen that's lg: 992px I want row display 2 columns but on smaller screens - md: 768px - I want single column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">1</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">2</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are Bootstrap 4 grid references [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) documentation.

Comment: Yes that one seems to work perfectly. I had no idea you can combine those classes this way hence the confusion. Now I know - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break differently, you have to use different breakpoint. Like this:

```
<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below fiddle:

[`Grid Breakdown`](https://jsfiddle.net/creative_singh/L05wug2x/)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x4rjp1gq/

```
<div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='col'>1</div>
        <div class='col'>2</div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='col'>3</div>
        <div class='col'>4</div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  text-align:center;
}
```